# cant download my sysstem app

Tags: root-access, lucky-patcher

I tried using  'PowerAMP', I converted it to a system app and then used lucky patcher rebuild and install. When I opened the application it failed to work, after uninstalling I am unable to install it from the play store and this is the error message I get,

> Can't install app with the same system user I.d

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the one in system app again.

Adb shell

Mount -o remount,rw /system

Cd /system/app

Cp appname backuppath

Rm appname

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the app and reinstall from playstore after a reboot. Then you can  start your adventure all over again. But this time don't rebuild a system app. Consider patching